How to use local API window service from web portal which is hosted on Server?
I have two projects: one is a Windows service which is running in the background and working as a Printing API. The another one is an ASP.NET MVC web application which is hosted on the server.
How can I set up API URL structure in the Windows service and how can I call from my web application?
Language is C#. Here is current API route config from the Windows service:
public WindowService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://*:8085/");
    HttpSelfHostServer server = null;

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );

    server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();

    LogEvent("Service started.");
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    server.CloseAsync().Wait();
    LogEvent("Service stopped.");
}

It is expected that the Windows service will be running on users' PC. When they call the website via browser, the call that Windows service and working process via API.

Looks like you need to create WebAPI instead of windows service. It then will expose indepoints that could be consumed. But, it should be hosted and run in a service with privileges to print (or access network printer) and the machine itself should open appropriate ports and be "publicly visible" for the web app hosted on server to be able to reach it (call printing endpoint).

What do you mean by "Printing API" exactly? Do you want / need to provide users a means to print on a printer that's local to you?

I used WebAPI and  it is solved.
